# High latency on webapp2 endpoint under appengine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, webapp2

I asked about this in the appengine user group [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine/hx_ffU7niBc) and wasn't able to resolve the issue.

The issue I'm having is that, for seemingly a very light endpoint and others like it, latency seems to be an issue. Here's an example request as shown in GCP's Trace tool:

[image]

I'm aware that if it's a request that spawned a new instance or if memory usage is high, that would explain high latency. Neither of which are the case here.

It seems that intermittently some endpoints simply take a good second or two to respond on top of however long the endpoint itself takes to do its job, and the bulk of that is "untraced time" under GCP Stackdriver's Trace tool. I put a log entry as early as I seemingly possibly could, in webapp2's RequestHandler object on initialization. You can see that in the screenshot as "webapp2 request init".

I'm not familiar enough with webapp2's inner working to know where I could put a log elsewhere that could help explain this, if anywhere.

These are the scaling settings for that appengine service defined in my `yaml` file:

```
instance_class: F4
automatic_scaling:
  max_idle_instances: 1
  max_pending_latency: 1s
  max_concurrent_requests: 50
```

Not sure what other information would be useful here.

Comment: I don't think that's webapp2, otherwise I'd expect you'd see it on most/all requests, not just intermittently. IMHO it's still something related to instance management. Try to add a global variable (shared by all requests hitting the same instance) to keep track of how many requests the instance served. Display that as well in your handler init log, then see if you can make a correlation between the displayed counts and the long response times.

Comment: did you ever solve this?